# Working macro in one workbook throws Error 1004 when ran in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving the `Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed` message in one macro in one workbook and am running the same macro another workbook where it runs successfully.  Is there an underlying requirement that I am missing?  After much research in a number of question and answer sites, I was not able to determine where the VBA code went out of range.

I am attempting to copy data from Tab1 (`Workforce Detail`) to Tab2 (`Current`) with varying selections from Tab1.  Each time the macro selects more data from Tab1, I want to copy and paste it to the first open row in Tab2.  I receive the error when specifying the active cell to begin the paste after the 2nd selection of data.

Here is the macro that is not working.  See my comments between astericks.

```
Sub SelectJobCode()
'
' SelectJobCode Macro
'

'
    Dim lastrow, currentlastrow As Long

 *** Clears the "Current" sheet (Tab2) in the workbook - no issues ***  

    Sheets("Current").Select       

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    With ActiveSheet
        currentlastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If currentlastrow > 1 Then
        Range("A2", Cells(currentlastrow, "ap")).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If

    Range("A2").Select

*** Goes to Workforce Detail sheet/tab (Tab1) to filter specific columns.  No issues ***


    Sheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Select    

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If lastrow > 1 Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
            Range(Cells(2, "g"), Cells(lastrow, "g")), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,  DataOption _
            :=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, "ap"))
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

*** Column 7 is Job Code.  Filter for Job Codes = "CA600" and "CA601".  No Issues.***

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, "ap")).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "CA600", "CA601"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

*** Determine row count in Tab1, select filtered data, go to "Current" sheet (Tab2), paste data beginning in cell A2.  No issues.  ***

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If lastrow > 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, "ap")).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Current").Select
        Range("A2").Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A2").Select
    End If

***Go back to Tab1.  Clear filters.  Refilter on 2 more job codes.  Determine the last row of filter data, select range to copy.  No issues  ****

    Sheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Select

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    Range("A2").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, "ap")).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "OK101", "OK102"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'        "OK111", "OK112", "OK202", "OK205", "OK206", "OK207" _
'        , "OK212", "OK314", "OK316", "SR007", "SR030", "YZ020"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

*** Select range of filtered data on Tab1 to prepare to paste to Tab2.  No issues.  ***

    If lastrow > 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, "ap")).Select
        Selection.Copy

*** Go to Tab2 "Current".  Determine the last row.  Add 1 to the last row. No issues.  ****

        Sheets("Current").Select
        Range("A2").Select

        With ActiveSheet
            currentlastrow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        currentlastrow = currentlastrow + 1

***  The above code works.  The value in currentlastrow is 256, exactly what I expect it to be.  ***


        MsgBox currentlastrow

*** ActiveSheet should still be "Current".  During the trial and error phase (before giving up and submitting my question here), I have added code to specify the sheet, with no luck***

        If currentlastrow > 1 Then

*** This next statement is where the error occurs.  ***
*** This very same syntax runs successfully in another workbook.  Is there some underlying cause specific to a given workbook?  Can you see why this statement is receiving the error?  What am I missing?  ***

            Range("A", Cells(currentlastrow)).Select
        Else
            Range("A2").Select
        End If

        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A2").Select
    End If

    Sheets("GHR-77025 Workforce Detail Repo").Select

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    Range("A2").Select

    MsgBox "Current tab formatted"  

End Sub
```

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: it's Range("A" **&** Cells(currentlastrow)).Select not Range("A"**,** Cells(currentlastrow)).Select I think

Comment: Alex- That should do it, I'd put it as the answer.

Comment: @user3357997: Welcome and great question. Well layed out and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

**It is:**

```
 Range("A" & currentlastrow).Select
```

**not**

```
Range("A", Cells(currentlastrow)).Select
```

(Use **"&"** instead of **","**)

Comment: Thank you, Alex, for the suggestion.  Replacing "&" with "," did not work.  Still receiving the same error.  Here is the updated line of code:  Range("A" & Cells(currentlastrow)).Select

Comment: @user3357997 Please also remove the Cells(), I have edited the answer, see if that fix the issue~